# 3-D Matrix Multiplication in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have to multiply two 2-D matrices, `bob` and `tim`, in Numpy Python 3.x

`bob.shape` gives `(2,4)`

`tim.shape` gives `(7,4)`

This piece of code gives a 3-D matrix with a shape of `(2,7,4)`

```
np.array([foo*tim for foo in bob])
```

It gives the output I want. But, I was wondering if there was a more elegant/faster way to do this in numpy rather than me having to iterate through `bob`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Python Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
bob.reshape((2, 1, 4)) * tim.reshape((1, 7, 4))
```